# Inline-меню в Telegram bot на C#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, telegram, menu, inline

Я новичок в C#, решил попробовать написать Telegram-бота. Подскажите пожалуйста, как на С# реализовать такое Inline-меню с отправкой mp3, чтобы можно было листать страницы, как показано на картинке? Бот на картинке - @fmusbot [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Подозреваю, что старое сообщение удаляется и вместо него отправляется новое.

Comment: Мне кажется кнопки "<" и ">" назначены на цикл в котором идёт переключение между массивами кнопок с ссылками на mp3, а кнопка по середине просто счетчик. Но я не знаю как это написать в коде.

Comment: @Qwerti прав. Стрелки просто затирают текущее сообщение и заменяют новым, отлавливайте нажатие стрелки и в зависимости от выбранной страницы меняйте сообщение.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev  То есть в параметре ReplyMarkup при нажатии кнопки нужно передать метод удаления? Или как?

Comment: Метод ``editMessageText`` в нём передаете ид старого сообщения, который будет заменен.

Comment: Возможно это поможет https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dCiUbCqEJwc&t=20s
Тут показывают как сделать страничное меню